# Matching a list of deformed strings to their correct values

Tags: algorithm

I have two lists, each contain 50 names.

There is a 1-1 correspondence between the two lists that satisfies: For each name x in list 1, there is a mis(or correct)spelling of x in list 2.

If I have list 1 and I am given the misspelled list 2, is there a reliable algorithm that will match the misspelled names to their correctly spelled counterparts?

For example,

List 1:
Bush
Obama
Trump

List 2:
Burts
Pbame
Tramp

Comment: You [probably] want the "Damerau Levenshtein Distance" algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 0):

First, compute the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) from every misspelled word to all of the correctly spelled word.

Then, using the [Gale-Shapley](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithme_de_Gale_et_Shapley) algorithm you can do the best pairing from misspelled to correctly spelled words.

In the pairing algorithm, each misspelled word will prefer a correctly spelled word whose distance is lower.

Note: there will always be cases where the solution is not unique.

Comment: O(N^2). Probably Ok for 50 names but not scalable.

Answer (score -1):

The most popular is definitely KMP, if you need fast string matching without any particular usecase in mind it’s what you should use. Here are your options(with time complexity):

Brute Force O(nm)

Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm - O(n)

Rabin–Karp string search algorithm - O(m^2) but Θ(n + m)

Boyer–Moore string search algorithm - O(mn)

Bitap algorithm - O(mn)

Two-way string-matching algorithm -O(n+m)

Comment: KMP will only find a searched substring in a string. If there is a spelling mistake in any of the strings KMP will not find it (because it only searches for equal strings).

Comment: Spitting the name of random algorithms without reasons is *not* an answer.